# Closing a NetworkStream after calling BeginRead() in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networkstream

I have implemented a system that mimics the DataReceived event of a serial port, whereby the reading of data from a TCPClient object's NetworkStream is triggered by using the BeginRead() method as follows:

```
TcpClient server = new TcpClient();
server.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 10001);
server.GetStream().BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), server.GetStream());
```

which calls the following method from another thread:

```
 private void DataReceived(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        res = result;
        server.GetStream().EndRead(result);

        //append received data to the string buffer
        stringBuffer += System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

        //clear the byte array
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        //trigger the parser
        waitHandle.Set();

        server.GetStream().BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), buffer);
    }
```

This appears to work correctly. I can send and receive data to a device on the network without issue. However, when I attempt to disconnect using the following method, the program crashes:

```
public override void disconnect()
{
    server.Close();
}
```

It throws the following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll
```

I have also tried implementing the disconnect method as follows:

```
server.GetStream().Close();
```

but this results in the following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
```

I assume this has something to do with the fact that the BeginRead() method has been called and the EndRead() method has not. If that is the case how can I close the stream without it crashing?

Comment: You need to use a try block around the EndRead() call so you can catch the ObjectDisposedException.  It is a reliable indicator that the socket got closed unexpectedly.

Comment: I've found the problem. I was getting a `'System.ObjectDisposedException'` because the EndRead() and BeginRead() method calls were not surrounded by try/catch blocks. When I closed the stream, these methods were attempting to execute on an object that no longer existed.

Comment: Check these answers, their are about the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096943/how-to-stop-reading-from-networkstream/43101953#comment73305491_43101953

Answer (score 1):

I would call `GetStream` just once and store the result somewhere and use that for accessing the stream.

```
Stream nstrm = server.GetStream();
```

Use `nstrm` for all accesses to the `NetworkStream`...

safest way would be to maintain a flag for closing down and just setting that flag in `disconnect()`.

In `DataReceived` you would directly after `EndRead` check for that flag and if it is set do this:

```
server.Close();
nstrm.Close();
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx

EDIT - as per comment:

```
if (flag2Close)
{
    server.Close();
    nstrm.Close();
    flag2Close = false;
}
else
{
    nstrm.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(DataReceived), buffer);
}
```

BTW: for production code it needs some exception handling etc.

Comment: This works, however since the flag is checked after EndRead() is called, data must be received before the connection can be terminated. So, if I were to connect, disconnect, then connect again, it would throw an error because the connection had never been closed. If I were to connect, disconnect, send some data, then connect again it would work.

Comment: I am not really sure I understand... the point where you handle the flag to close the TcpClient and the Stream is totally up to you - you could even put the check directly before the next BeginRead and only do the BeginRead IF the flag is false... see my edit above

Comment: Yes, but when the BeginRead() method is called, it calls back the method DataReceived and blocks until data is received. This means the flag will not be checked until the next iteration of the method, which occurs when data is received.

Comment: you can use the WaitHandle with a timeout - this way you don't need to wait till data is really received - for code sample see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388771/difference-between-networkstream-read-and-networkstream-beginread/4389026#4389026