# C# Threaded messages with TcpClient (various errors)

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to sent 500 messaged over a TCP connection and receive a response for each message within limited time, using threading to remain within the time. This is new to me and I spent a lot of time searching the forums before I put it up here, so please be patient.

The best result so far I had was with some variation of:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for(int i=1;i<500;i++)
{
    Task task = new Task(new SendMessage(Message(i)).Send);
    tasks.Add(task);
}
```

then

```
foreach(Task task in tasks)
{
    task.Start();
}

// Keep track of time (stay within 30s)
Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
s.Start();
while (s.ElapsedMilliseconds < 30000)
{
    Console.WriteLine((int)(0.001 * s.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

and then

```
public class SendMessage
{
    byte[] msg;
    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    NetworkStream stm;

    public void Send()
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

            tcpclnt.Connect("IPADDRESS", port);

            stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            stm.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);

            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stm))
            {
                while (xmlReader.Read())
                {
                    string requestID = String.Empty;
                    string message = String.Empty;

                    if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "requestID"))
                    {
                        requestID = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml();
                        sw.Write("requestID\t" + requestID + "\t");
                        Console.WriteLine("requestID\t" + requestID + "\t");
                    }
                    else if ((xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xmlReader.Name == "message"))
                    {
                        message = xmlReader.ReadInnerXml();
                        sw.WriteLine("message\t" + message);
                        Console.WriteLine("message\t" + message);

                        xmlReader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Send();
        }
    }
    public SendMessage(  string msg)
    {
        this.msg = asen.GetBytes(msg);  
    }
}
```

But the application keeps crashing in the reading part. The error I get in this example is

> XMLException - root element is missing

The try/catch block seems to work but the error is so frequent that it slows the application down to the extent that I cannot keep time consumption acceptable.

Variations I tried involved

1. using  a global static TCPClient that connects in Main instead of in Send()
2. using NetworkStream either global or local in SendMessage
3. parcing TCPClient as a reference
4. using threads instead of tasks
5. using other thread-safe reader types (when using threads)

Comment: What is the problem you are having, you explained what you are doing and showed us what you tried but you are missing what went wrong with what you tried. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26487857/edit) to add the details of what errors or incorrect behavior you are getting.

Comment: you might want to remove the ip address too

Comment: I'd go for async socket IO, preferably with an existing TCP/IP infrastructure (such as WCF or Protobuf). There are plenty of examples on the web on how to do this... Correctly implementing sockets can be tricky, so it makes little sense to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Also. your try catch is not slowing down your app. Its the 500 threads that you are spawning..

Comment: The catch is often hit with the error (XML root element is missing) and resending the messages - i think - is time consuming.

Comment: What makes you think that multiple threads will make this go faster? If all of the requests are going to the same server, your limiting factors are the communication bandwidth and the server's ability to respond.

Comment: Is your question regarding the XML exception or is it about the proper use of a TCP connection pool? if its the former, then the problem is simple, you're trying to read an invalid XML which is missing a root element.

Answer (score 2):

In a TCP connection you can send to and receive from the socket at the same time, but you cannot send or receive from multiple threads each.

The best thing to use the producer/consumer pattern, so you can send without waiting and get notified when a message arrives: [How to: Implement a Producer-Consumer Dataflow Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also, you need some framing protocol to send things through a socket, to let the other end know where a message starts or ends. That is why is missing part of the file.

I recommends you to take a look at WCF: [Windows Communication Foundation [.NET Framework 4.0]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue you are having is you are not waiting for a response before you read from the stream. [The accepted answer here shows how to wait for a response before reading.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388771/difference-between-networkstream-read-and-networkstream-beginread) Although there is other complexities to consider, this is should fix your current issue. If your messages are large (over ~1.5 KB, or your default mtu size), just because you have received some data on your socket, doesn't mean you have received all your data on the socket. So you will need some sort of framing for your XML response. Which leads to the other answer, have you considered looking into WCF or web service producer/consumers?